# CMTimeGetSeconds doesn't get the right video duration

Tags: ios, iphone, video, ffmpeg

some users don't get the right duration of videos they capture with their own device. The funny thing is others do actually see it right, using the same device models and OS version. Anyway, we observed it in a iPhone 5c 7.1.2 and an iPhone 5s 8.1.3.

This code works for most users, but not all:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [mediaObject.asset defaultRepresentation];
NSURL *url = [representation url];
NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };
AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:options];
videoDurationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(avAsset.duration);
```

I asked them to send the input videos, and this is the output from "ffmpeg -i"

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bug_duration1.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-02-23 08:30:01
    encoder         : 8.1.3
    encoder-eng     : 8.1.3
    date            : 2015-02-23T16:30:01+0800
    date-eng        : 2015-02-23T16:30:01+0800
    model           : iPhone 5s
    model-eng       : iPhone 5s
    make            : Apple
    make-eng        : Apple
  Duration: 00:00:03.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16793 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16719 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-23 08:30:01
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-23 08:30:01
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

The video is detected with a duration of several minutes. Did anybody face this problem before?

Thanks in advance.